# Calculate random integer inside a range of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, functions, definition, random

$$F : \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb N $$
$$F(\text{minReal},\ \text{maxReal}) = \text{randomInt} \in \left[\text{minReal},\ \text{maxReal}\right] $$

Let $r \in [0, 1)$ be a random value. How can I define the above function F?

Note that a simple expression like:
$$F(\text{minReal},\ \text{maxReal}) = \operatorname{round}(r (\text{maxReal} - \text{minReal}) + \text{minReal})$$
doesn't work because it may return an integer $\notin \left[\text{minReal},\ \text{maxReal}\right]$.

Comment: I would say that F(minReal,maxReal)=minReal + round()*(maxReal-minReal)

Comment: @georg 1. round() doesn't make sense, you mean r (or rand()) 2. F should return an integer number, not a real number!

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

If exists an integer number between minFloat and maxFloat this should work:

let min = ceil(minFloat)

let max = floor(maxFloat)

F(minFloat, maxFloat) = floor(r * (max - min + 1) + min)

Answer (score 0):

$\large\tt C++$:

```
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
const double RANDMAX1=double(RAND_MAX) + 1.0;

inline double rand01() // Return random in [0,1)
{
 return rand()/RANDMAX1;
}


// Return random in [minVal,maxVal)
double randMinMax(double minVal,double maxVal)
{
 const double d=maxVal - minVal;
 double x;
 do x=minVal + rand01()*d; while (  ( x<minVal ) || ( x>maxVal )  );
 return x;
}
```

${\large\tt javaScript}$:

```
function randMinMax(minVal,maxVal)
{
 var d=maxVal - minVal,x;

 do x=minVal + Math.random()*d; while (  ( x<minVal ) || ( x>maxVal )  );
 return x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But for performance would be better not to try and try again if the value is not in range. I've already found a simple expression that solves the problem (see my answer above).

Comment: @collimarco Just to be sure !!!. I'm sure it seldom retry...